# What's a good web system for sharing photos amongst co-workers?

Tags: software, web, service-recommendation

I work for a company where we quite often are doing internal events, seminars, and party's. This offen ends up with quite a lot of pictures, from both the company dSLR but also coworkers that bring their cameras.

I am looking for a good way to share these amongst the company, essencally a online photodatabase.

The requirements that this must meet is:

**Events Based Photo Sharing**
We want to be able to share photos of events, so there has to be a grouping feature.

**Private**
Only company members can see the uploaded pictures.

**Downloadale images**
Easy download of uploaded pictures.

**Comments/Description**
Not the most important thing, but it would be nice.

**Easy upload**
Everyone can upload pictures to a event, as all members are trusted workers.

Self-hosted would be a nice thing, as nobody else would have the pictures, and all rights are ours.

Active Directory login would be nice.

Do you know any services or applications that can do this? It would not hurt if it was open source as we like to add new features ect.

Comment: Microsoft SharePoint.

Comment: In the spirit of equal time, if you're a Notes shop, a decent developer could put together a Domino web (intranet) app that does the job nicely before lunch (but after coffee, obviously).

Comment: In either case of those cases, you _will_ want that intranet developer. And if you have the choice, save that poor person's sanity and use Django instead of either one. I'm just sayin'.

Comment: The intranet developer will most likely be me. I would not go with SharePoint, too much bloat, and not that friendly for photos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a current round of updates to Media functionality in the last few months, I am finding that WordPress (self-hosted) is becoming my go-to solution for photo sharing. Here is how using WordPress can meet your requirements:

**Events Based Photo Sharing**

How you define an 'event' and 'grouping' is certainly up to interpretation, but if you were to create a post type of 'Event', a gallery of photos can be attached to each event post to keep a logical hierarchy. Filtering that grouping with metadata like Categories or Tags (supported out-of-box in WordPress) allows for free-form taxonomy across all media and posts. Additionally, if you need WordPress to handle more event management beyond grouping events, there are plugins available for that level of detailed event management: [Events](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-events/)

**Private**

WordPress by default provides an authentication and authorization system, but if you have another service (Google, Facebook, Twitter, LDAP, [Active Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/active-directory-integration/), etc etc etc) that you prefer to use for one or both of those purposes, the plugins are available, and most are battled-tested. Again, this is personal preference as to what is the most unifying way to provide people access without having to necessarily create 'yet another another password'.

**Downloadable Images**

The simplest way I can imagine doing this with WordPress is attaching a gallery of images to a post, with a .zip attached containing all the images uploaded and a link provided. Latitude to be creative with this requirement is pretty wide.

**Comments/Description**

Two different things, in most contexts. Again, especially with recent updates, WordPress Media functionality is very robust, and all levels of image description (written description down to metadata/RDF) data fields are provided for each photo. Commenting, by default, is available in WordPress at the Post level.

**Easy Upload**

Ease of access to the upload system depends on your authentication/authorization provider, but the newest iterations of WordPress allow drag-and-dropping of images right into the Media library.

WordPress is open-source and self-hosted, with less than a five minute install in most cases.

Comment: Ah yes, Wordpress could be the solution. I just need to work with some addons or something like that, I don't want the blog format for keeping the pictures.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen You could also have a look at Drupal, it also has a bunch of modules related to gallery.

Comment: By far with plugins, WordPress will definitely be the lowest effort and most flexible option, given the massive presence of this product. Some of my suggestions were low effort to get up and running, but I agree that there is a plugin for each requirement on your list

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Piwigo](http://piwigo.org), open source gallery software for the web.

**Events Based Photo Sharing**: you can group your photos by album. Piwigo supports several levels of albums (as much as you need).

**Private**: you can make the whole gallery private or just make a few albums or photos private. User "john" may be permitted to see album "eventA" and "eventB" and user "paul" can only see "eventC". The webmaster decides.

**Downloadale images**: Piwigo let the visitor download photo one by one. If you want to download several at once, install and activate plugin Batch Downloader.

**Comments/Description**: core features.

**Easy upload**: web upload, FTP and applications like pLoader, Lightroom, iPhoto, Aperture, shotwell, digiKam. Applications for iOS and Android.

**Active Directory**: a plugin for LDAP is under preparation, I think it will be compatible with Active Directory.

More than 200 extensions are currently available for Piwigo 2.4

Answer (score -1):

I do like 500px.com and the services they offer for the paid accounts (ability to make "sets" private + password protected as well as print from the sets).
On personal hosting setup, there's gallery2 open source project (http://galleryproject.org/) that is highly customizable and fairly easy to setup.